# iPhone Application using Web Services

Tags: .net, iphone, web-services

Hey im looking to developed some webservices for an Iphone, id like to do this in  a .NET environment.

Whats the best way to get started i.e.

Can I just go ahead and create the webservices I need first off all like any other webservice or does there need to be some consideration since these webservice will be built for IPhone.

Also my Webservices will look something getAllJobs whatever and pull down a bunch of data which is fine, is it always possible to update details on a job and send this back via another webservice. ?

And lastly how does the actual UI for the Iphone get developed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Rob.  Have a look at http://www.mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/

Answer (score 0):

You should code your web services (in general) without any regard to the consumer.  Ideally, should you strive for a RESTFUL design since this makes it easier to use.

As for the "How does the UI get developed", well they're tons of on-line and hardcopy sources to get started with this.  Some of the best books for a beginning are:

[Beginnning iPhone Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430224592)